# How to call stored procedure through Entity Framework using an object as the parameters?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I have a stored procedure that I'm calling from a Web API that takes 20 parameters for an insert. I have an object that has those twenty parameters filled. I need to call the stored procedure and pass the object as the data for the procedure. Will this map automatically if the names are the same, or do I need to do something to avoid doing

```
context.storedProc(par1,par2,par3,par4,...,par20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map the parameters of a function import mapped to a stored procedure, but you can easily map the output to a complex type such as a POCO or something.

An alternative is that you can have an entity in the data context that is mapped to the procedure for inserts/updates/etc that is called when `SaveChanges` on the data context attempts to save tracked changes on that entity. This could help you avoid long parameter lists by using the column mapping of the entity to the stored proc.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716711(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @alexkibler If the answer helped you, please consider clicking the up arrow next to the answer. If the answer solved your question, please click the check mark under the down arrow. These things help others know your question is solved and which answers have helped, and your reputation will also increase.